# No valid Qt versions found

Tags: qt, qt-creator

Qt Creator is complaining about

> No valid Qt versions found

when I try and make a new project. It also says

> Please add a Qt version in Tools/Options or via the maintenance tool of the SDK

When I go to tools/Options, it says:

> Qt 4.8.1 in PATH (System) /usr/bin/qmake-qt4

But there's a red sign by it with an exclamation mark.

I have looked on Google but there's no solution that works for me. I installed Qt Creator and the SDK, and have build-essentials.

Answer (score 1):

I think problem is, you need to update toolchain with your Qt version.

[Qt Creator won't recognize any Qt version](https://askubuntu.com/questions/85970/qt-creator-wont-recognize-any-qt-version)

Answer (score 1):

Turns out the path to gcc was wrong